# Securely locked driver update [16.04]

Tags: dual-boot, intel-graphics, gpu-driver

I have been dual booting recently because I need Ubuntu for work and such but I ran into a small issue. Firing up a video I noticed the fan ramping up faster than in Windows. From a search I learned that VA-API is not installed by default, so the CPU was being taxed more than I'd like. This would make video editing even slower and slightly more taxing on the hardware.

I am aware of 01.org but it seems sketchy with that name, especially when it said the driver could not be installed securely and whenever the 01 repository was added updating always ran into an error. I have to keep secure boot on so I have to ask a rather simple yet dumb question...

Is there a way to enable VA-API for the intel platform without disabling secure boot? I know most 3rd party options are out...

Comment: You can self sign the key - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/SecureBoot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forcing hardware acceleration through MPV worked, didn't need to sign the keys or anything. Still uses 20% (4K 60FPS)CPU on all cores but it's better than 45% on all of them (720P 24 FPS)